# how to use preg_replace from javascript result and store as double data type into db

Tags: javascript, php, preg-replace

i'm new in php,

i have result from javascript **Rp.320.468,75**
and i want to transfrom become **320468.75** using preg_replace to store as double in my db.

i try to using with this following code

```
preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$this->input->post('sub_total'))
```

but the result give **32046875**

i want the result like this => **320468.75**

thank you for helping,

best regards.. :)

Comment: Have you tried [parsing it as currency](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parsecurrency.php)

Comment: yeah mr adeneo. the result More or less like that. but i want to using preg_replace for manipulate the javascript result in php. 

thank you for you response.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A really simple solution is using more `str_replace` and replace characters one at time. So you can do this:

```
str_replace(",", ".", str_replace(".", "", str_replace("Rp", "", $this->input->post('sub_total'))));
```

Comment: very nice mr felixfrog,that's code working. i never knew the str_replace function can used in multiple.
thank you very much... :)